# GeoServer 2.10.4 - Vector layer always on top

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have successfully created a new vector layer in my GeoServer 2.10.4. It shall be displayed on top of a basemap and an additional raster layer, but it displays below the raster. I want this order:

1. Basemap
2. Raster
3. Vector

But got this one:

1. Basemap
2. Vector
3. Raster

How can I change this, so the vector layer always sits on top of everything else? From various similar questions I found that it should be achievable using the SLD of the layer and inserting `z-order=X` somewhere, so here is my SLD for this particular layer. I tried values of `0`, `1` and `99` so far, all with the same result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
 xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
 xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <!-- a Named Layer is the basic building block of an SLD document -->
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>default_polygon</Name>
    <UserStyle>
    <!-- Styles can have names, titles and abstracts -->
      <Title>Default Polygon</Title>
      <Abstract>A sample style that draws a polygon</Abstract>
      <!-- FeatureTypeStyles describe how to render different features -->
      <!-- A FeatureTypeStyle for rendering polygons -->
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>rule1</Name>
          <Title>Red Polygon with Black Outline</Title>
          <Abstract>A polygon with a red fill and a 1 pixel black outline</Abstract>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#ff0000</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="z-index">99</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: Currently supported versions are 2.13.2 and 2.12.5, and 2.14 will soon be there. You should consider an upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

The SLD Z-order is used to determine the order that *features* are drawn in the *layer* not the order of the layers. The layer order is controlled by the client that you are using, it needs to make the requests in the correct order.

Comment: true, or from the Layer Group configuration.

Comment: Understood. So how can I achieve this then? Sorry, but I'm very new to GeoServer and we only have this version installed at the moment.

Comment: you need to add details of the client you are using to the question